# Partially correct generic linked list using void*

Tags: c, pointers, generics, linked-list, polymorphism

Code is an experiment implementing a Generic Linked List in C.

As `void` pointer is it can be used to point to any data type and size of all types of pointers is always is same, so can always allocate a linked list node. Function pointer is needed to process actual content stored at address pointed by void pointer.

Works only partially, suspect problems using `char*`.

Main:

```
nodePtr start = createList();
// Create and print an int linked list
unsigned int_size = sizeof(int);
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, i;
for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
  start= push(start, &arr[i], int_size);}

// Results in 10, 20,40 being stored and doesn't read 30,50!
```

Code:

```
struct node
{
  // Any data type can be stored in this node
  void  *data;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
typedef node* nodePtr;
typedef nodePtr* ptrNodePtr;

nodePtr head, tail;
int listSize;

nodePtr push(nodePtr head_ref, void *new_data, size_t data_size)
{

  // Allocate memory for node
  nodePtr new_node = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));

  new_node->data  = malloc(data_size);
  new_node->next = NULL;

  // Copy contents of new_data to newly allocated memory.
  // Assumption: char takes 1 byte.
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<data_size; i++)
    *(char *)(new_node->data + i) = *(char *)(new_data + i);

  // Change head pointer as new node is added at the beginning
  if (listSize ==0) {
    //printf("%d",listSize);
    head_ref = new_node;  }
  else{
    printf("%d",listSize);
    head_ref[listSize-1].next =  new_node;
  }
  listSize++;
  return head_ref;
}

nodePtr createList() {
  head = NULL;
  tail = NULL;
  listSize = 0;
  return head;
}
```

Comment: `new_node->data + i` is an error, you cannot use arithmetic on `void *`. If you don't see a compiler warning then adjust your settings.  You should replace that entire loop with `memcpy(new_node->data, new_data, data_size);`

Comment: `head_ref[listSize-1]` is a logic error. Each node resides in a separate memory allocation, but you are indexing off one node as if all of the nodes are part of an array. The code comment suggests you want new nodes to be inserted at the beginning; in that case you would not make any changes to the existing first node; you would set `new_node->next = head_ref;` instead , and return `new_node;` in all cases

Comment: To store the size of each data added in the linked-list, it should be useful to a field `size_t size;` in the `struct node`. Otherwise, if the size is not a constant for all the linked-list, no way to recover the data except the pointer.